# Change cursor on datagrid row

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, cursor

I'm working on a flex project, and have a datagrid that I'd like the cursor to change when hovering over any row containing data.

I have double click enable on the datagrid and I'd like to indicate to the use that they can click the row they are hovering over.

This is what I've tried but it seems to just use the hand cursor on the datagrid its self and not the row data.

```
    <mx:DataGrid x="9" y="47" width="330" height="244" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" mouseChildren="true" horizontalScrollPolicy="{ScrollPolicy.AUTO}" styleName="resultgrid" dataProvider="{acLatest}" doubleClickEnabled="true" itemDoubleClick="doubleClickoverview()"  id="overviewLatest_dg">
     <mx:columns>                   
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Tag" id="overviewLatest_dg_animal_ptag" visible="true" dataField="animal_ptag" width="110" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Status" id="overviewLatest_dg_status_status" visible="true" dataField="status_status" width="110"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Sex" id="overviewLatest_dg_animal_sex" visible="true" dataField="animal_sex" width="110"/>
     </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using itemRollOver & itemRollOut on the datagrid.

Then just created a simple class that changes the cursor to a hand image.

**DataGrid:**

```
itemRollOver="Cursors.setHandCursor()" itemRollOut="CursorManager.removeAllCursors()"
```

**Cursor Class:**

```
package com {

  import mx.managers.CursorManager;
  import mx.managers.CursorManagerPriority;

  public class Cursors extends CursorManager {

    private static var handCursorList:Array = [];

    public static function setHandCursor():void {   
      [Embed(source="../images/hand.png")]   
      var handCursorClass:Class;
      handCursorList.push(setCursor(handCursorClass, CursorManagerPriority.MEDIUM));
    }  
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an `itemRenderer` and add event listeners for the `MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER` and `MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT` events. In the event handlers you can change the cursor using the `cursorManager`. This also has the added benefit of allowing you to change the cursor based on some data or condition for the row the user is hovering their cursor over.

[Here's an example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/10/changing-the-cursor-in-a-flex-application-using-the-cursormanager-class/) on changing the cursor when mousing over a component. Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction.